# Is there a way to figure out, in retrospect, what features the App Wizard selected for my vc++ 2010 mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++

I an a novice VC++ programmer.  I like my recent application's exe file but stupidly forgot to note all of the choices that I specified to the Wizard (project "style", shared DLL vs static library, etc).  How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

The project "style" is MFC Appliction if it generates an exe file. Library projects do not generate an exe file.

Beyond that, choices such as application type and type of menu/ribbon can easily be seen by using the wizard to create a bunch of MFC apps with the various options.